# Play! framework: no data received

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

this is a route I defined:
`GET   /user/:id                    controllers.Users.show(id: Long)`

this is the handler (in `Users` class) for this GET requset:

```
public static Result show(long id) {
        return ok("hello " + id);
    }
```

I get this error:

> No data received
>   Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
>   Here are some suggestions:
>   Reload this webpage later.
>   Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

this is weird because it's the only page with this problem and everything seems to be normal.
so why is it happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Long` as `id`'s type (instead of `long`):

```
public static Result show(Long id) {
    return ok("hello " + id);
}
```